# How to run the code in command line application via Python

Tags: python, command-line

I need to run a bat file (P:/myBat.bat) in a specific application (for example, located in C:/temp/myApp.exe). Manually I launch myApp.exe, run the code

```
hscript P:/myBat.bat
```

And I get what I need. But I wish to do it with Python.

I know how to execute a bat file with Python:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("P:/myBat.bat").communicate()
```

But how to execute `hscript P:/myBat.bat` via myApp.exe with Python?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `subprocess.call`, e.g. `subprocess.call(['hscript', 'P:/myBat.bat'])`, and its friends. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Comment: But where should I set path to my command line application(C:/temp/myApp.exe))?

Comment: The `hscript` is unregistered command in Windows (from myApp.exe)

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you probably want to set the working directory in which Python executes the subprocess. This is `os.chdir`, `os.getcwd`, etc.: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir

Comment: I have a command line application. I need to run a code (`hscript P:/myBat.bat`) in this application.
`subprocess.call(["C:/temp/myApp.exe", "hscript P:\myBat.bat" ])` runs the app but does not execute  the code in this app.

Comment: It would help if you pasted the output, but you may want to try `subprocess.call(["C:/temp/myApp.exe", "hscript", "P:\myBat.bat"])`

Comment: I tried such an option (actual code):
`subprocess.call(["C:/Program Files/Side Effects Software/Houdini 17.0.459/bin/hcmd.exe", "hscript", "P:\render.cmd"], shell=True)`, no luck as well.

Output:
`C:\Python27\python.exe P:/PROJECTS/NSI/PREP/PIPELINE/EVE/tools/batchRender.py
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1087]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

P:\PROJECTS\NSI\PREP\PIPELINE\EVE\tools>`

Comment: And this one `subprocess.call(["C:/Program Files/Side Effects Software/Houdini 17.0.459/bin/hcmd.exe", 'P:/render.cmd'], shell=True)` gives:
`C:\Python27\python.exe P:/PROJECTS/NSI/PREP/PIPELINE/EVE/tools/batchRender.py
Welcome to the Houdini 17.0.459 command line tools.
The Houdini environment has been initialized. [windows-x86_64-cl19.16]
Starting command prompt...'ender.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
`

Comment: I doubt that those invocations work from the command line either. :) You will first need to figure out a command that works from the shell, and then translate it into Python.